# JavaScript | Access the object of a Promise from another Promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, redux, es6-promise

In my AngularJS Application, I want to access the return value of a Promise, which I access from a service outside of my controller and import it there. This Promise, return an object. I want to access that objects and properties inside it.

I created the service to get that endpoint. Look below:

```
export const getEndpoints = () => {
  const options = {
    method: httpMethod.GET,
    url: endpoint.ENVIRONMENT,
  };
  return Instance(options);
};
```

The above service in return reads an endpoint which I provide and uses `axios` on the background. This part is working just fine.

Then imported it, on my angular Controller:

```
import { getEndpoints } from './config/service';
```

Finally I created this function:

```
$scope.isItAvailable = false; // I will use this later to check the actual value. It is not important in the scope of the question..

  const checkIfItIsAvailable = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(getEndpoints)
      console.log(getEndpoints)
    })
  }

  // And in my main function I am just calling the above
  const mainFn = () => {
    checkIfItIsAvailable()
    // Along with a few others..
  }
```

**Actual Results**
Now, in my console, I get the function`checkIfItAvailable` printed out.

**Expected Results**
I instead want to print to the console, the actual value that is being returned by the original promise, the object, and its properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably You need to call that function instead of just passing it as a parameter.

```
const checkIfItIsAvailable = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(getEndpoints()) // here
      console.log(getEndpoints())
    })
  }
```

Then to get that resolved later in your main function, or wherever - just use `then`:

```
const mainFn = () => {
    checkIfItIsAvailable().then((result) => {
       // do what you need with result here
       // $scope.isItAvailable = result   probably like this
    });
}
```

Please comment if you need another result. I see at least this issue at the moment.

Also, here is a snipper, illustrating that you need to call it instead of just passing.

```js
// here is an example function which just return some string
function getSomething() {
  return 'something'; // it could be a promise also
}

// here is example without calling functions, but just passing:
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log('NO CALL: ', getSomething);
});

// here is example with calling, so value is resolved
const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log('CALLED: ', getSomething());
});
```

Comment: No, it gets called on its one. It was set up this way long time ago. I will try it though just to be sure. Thanks..

Comment: @DimitrisEfst I've added code snipper, illustrating that you need to call function.

Answer (score 0):

Here, `getEndpoints` is an asynchronous function which returns a Promise, and the way to get a return value from promise is to use `then` callback. You can do it like this:

```
const checkIfItIsAvailable = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      getEndpoints().then(resultOfEndPoint => {
        console.log(resultOfEndPoint);
        resolve(resultOfEndPoint);
      });
    })
  }
```

Comment: With this says res is not defined... Also, you need a comma between the console.log() and resolve(). Thanks though. If you can update it, I will upvote. But I think I will go with artem's solution below...

Answer (score -1):

It's possible to access the resolved result of `getEndpoints` in `checkIfItIsAvailable` calling `getEndpoints()` and using `then() function`:

```
const checkIfItIsAvailable = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // call getEndpoints
    getEndpoints()
      // call then to get a result from getEndpoints
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        // checkIfItIsAvailable will be resolved with
        // the result of getEndpoints
        resolve(res);
      });
  });
}
```